# Check last value of an drop-down option select box with jquery

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu, html-select

I am trying to get the last option from a drop down Select box with jquery.

I do this:

```
var maxOpt = $('#status option:last-child').val();
if (maxOpt != "SHIPPED") {
    console.log(maxOpt);
}
```

Console keeps printing undefined, even if the last option is SHIPPED.

---

FULL CODE

```
<script>
                    $(document).ready(function() {

                      $("#source").change(function() {

                        var el = $(this) ;
                        var sel = document.getElementById('statusList');
                        var maxOpt = $('#status option:last-child').val();
                        if((el.val() === "ONLINE" || el.val() === "ETSY") && maxOpt !="SHIPPED") {
                        $("#statusList").append("<option value='shipped'>SHIPPED</option>");
                        console.log(maxOpt);
                        }
                          else if(el.val() === "MANUAL" ) {
                            $("#statusList option:last-child").remove() ; }
                      });

                    });
                </script>
```

Comment: is you code in DOM ready ??

Comment: Works for me http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/hZGcX/

Comment: posted full code, cannot get it to work on my side

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works for me  **http://jsfiddle.net/zvkCp/** Maybe is a problem with your selector :

```
$('#status option:last-child')

$(document).ready (function() {
  var maxOpt = $('select option:last-child').val();
  if (maxOpt != 'cuatro'){
    console.log(maxOpt);
  }
})
```

Try to `console.log(maxOpt)` off the if condition.

Answer (score 2):

try using [`last`](http://api.jquery.com/last-selector/)

```
 $('#status option:last')
```

[**JSFIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/hZGcX/1/)

Comment: @samyb8, check the fiddle link in my answer. It works fine. What browser and version do you use?

Comment: yes I see. I posted the full code in case I am missing something. Can't find where...

Comment: @samyb8. check [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hZGcX/4/). Also what is `status` and `statusList`? two elements?

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function() {
    var lastOpt = $('#status').find('option:last-child').attr('value');
    if (lastOpt === 'SHIPPED') { //blah }
});
```